# MVC: Creare sub folders under View

Tags: .net, mvc

I am working on a small ERP Application and using MVC5 for it.

I have several Modules in the application and each module contain several web pages (Views, you can say).

i.e: for School application
I have LibraryManagement/Hostel Management

Now under view folder I want to create my folder structure as following:

**Views**

1. Library [Physical Folder]

   - BookManagement  [Controller]

     - Add/Edit/Delete Book Detail. [Action Based Views]
   - Issue Book.
   - Generate Library Card
2. Hostel [Physical Folder]

   - RoomInfo [Controller Name]

     - AddRoom [Action Based View]
     - EditRoom [Action Based View]
     - ListRoom [Action Based View]
   - Assign Room [Controller]
   - AssignRoom [Action Based View]
   - Manage Fees
   - EditFeesInfo [Action Based View]

Please help me how can I create this structure in MVC 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is a [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), hence, your controllers should never be in your Views folder (and vice versa). If I were you, I'd simply create a folder "Library" and "Hostel" in your project root. Then add a "Controllers" and "Views" folder for each. I suppose both share the same Models, so I'd put these in a separate folder in the root.

If you really want to separate the "Library" and "Hostel" part in your application, you can work with [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin the concept of `Areas` perfectly worked in my application. :-)

Thanks Buddy

Comment: Awesome! That's good to hear.